# Method of Frobenius to solve $x^2 Y''(x) + x Y'(x) = c^2 Y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I'm trying to 
$x^2 Y''(x) + x Y'(x) = c^2 Y(x)$ 
using the method of Frobenius. I assume the solution is of the form $Y = x^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^n $ and then put that into my ODE and found $0 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n[(n+k)(n+k-1)+(n+k)-c^2]x^{k+n} $. Then I found the indicial polynomial to be $a_0[k^2 - c^2]x^k = 0$ which means $k = c$. This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to solve the equation after knowing this part. 
I was trying to follow http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html.

Comment: I suppose that one of the $Y''$ is $Y'$.

Comment: Maple gives $y(x)=c_1 x^{-c} + c_2 x^c$. You may see how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $k= \pm c$.  This equation is really an Euler equation, so using Frobenius is overkill.  You should get that $a_0$ and $a_1$ are arbitrary constants and that all the other $a_n$'s are zero.

Comment: I still can't figure this out, so I'm not using Frobenius anymore.